# React component - continue working also when not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, single-page-application

I have a single page React app. The App.js decides what page to show, according to information from the server. There is a Stopwatch component, which rendered only with 2 of the pages. This is the code, from App.js:

```
render() {
  switch (this.state.patientState) {
      case statesEnum.WAITING:
        main = <WaitingPage socketClient={this.socketClient} />;
        break;
      case statesEnum.TURN_ARRIVED:
        main = <TurnArrivedPage />;
        break;
      case statesEnum.END:
        return <EndPage />; // Because we don't need a stopper here...
      default:
        return <h1>Error...</h1>;
   }

   return (
     <main>
       <Stopwatch initialSeconds={this.state.seconds} initialMinutes={this.state.minutes} initiallHours={this.state.hours} />
       {main}
     </main>
   );
}
```

But I want the stopper to continue counting up, even when it's not rendered on the screen. What can I do?

Thank's!

Comment: the stopper component to continue the counting also when it's now shown? What do you mean?

Comment: I want the stopper to continue counting up, even when it's not rendered on the screen

Comment: Now I can understand. In which component is the code attached to the question?

Comment: App.js. The main component.

Comment: And where is the render method in the App.js component? I suppose what you want should be done there.

Comment: you put the code for the stop watch in the parent - that is rendered (App in your case), and you make the Stopwatch component stateless i.e. it renders from props provided by parent.  Extra: even better if you split the management of the state into another component (Add this to App), and the render part into another child component stateless component. The management component, should be able to control visibility too

Comment: Sorry, I probably had to mention that. This code is the render method. I will update the question.

Comment: OK. So this is what I will do. Thank you!

Comment: let me know how you get on - if you can post more details of App it would help

Comment: you want something like this: <App><StopwatchMgr><StopwatchRndr /></StopWatchMgr></App>  if that makes sense.  where App and StopwatchMgr are always rendered.  but StopwatchRndr is rendered as required.   The stopwatch data is held in state n the StopwatchMgr.  But you might want to expose a showStopwatch prop up to parent (App), but visibility is controlled by StopwatchMgr, which toggles rendering StopwatchRndr

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: <StopWatch> tag is not closed in the code above

`<Stopwatch initialSeconds={this.state.seconds} initialMinutes={this.state.minutes} initiallHours={this.state.hours}`

Comment: It should be: `<Stopwatch initialSeconds={this.state.seconds} initialMinutes={this.state.minutes} initiallHours={this.state.hours} />`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. Thank you.

Comment: @developer with <StopwatchMgr><StopwatchRndr /></StopWatchMgr>, How does the StopwatchMgr pass the data into StopwatchRndr? As far as I know, StopwatchMgr just gets it from props.children. So how is the data passed there? (I hope you understood my question. I don't know exactly how to describe it...)

Comment: I mean, I can't do something like that: `<StopwatchManager><StopwatchRender seconds={seconds}, minutes={minutes}, hours={hours}</StpowatchManager>` - So how sould I do that?

Comment: you can - if you add the StopwatchRnd component in the render method of StopwatchMgr, instead of the render method of the App.. i.e. App renders a StopwatchMgr (aka Stopwatch) -> StopwatchMgr renders a StopwatchRndr

Comment: So do not pass `StopwatchMgr` as a child prop?

Comment: do not pass stopwatchRndr as child prop -  it is a rendered component of the manager - so the manager is managing it :)

Comment: your App then is just the App, and your stopwatch is all self contained.  your stopwatch can expose a prop to App(or any parent ) that allows it to have some control of visibility, but not the actual workings.  you can enhance this to expose a reset prop, or a pause prop etc.  you can then have multiple stopwatches, all independant

Comment: note/FYI: you can do this too: `<App><Stopwatch><StopwatchRender /></Stopwatch>` because you can access child still from Stopwatch using internal methods - react router does this.  It can make the usage of your components more flexible, as you can choose a stopwatch renderer, and control buttons (pause, reset etc..), in your App, but needs a lot more wiring, but is very nice, but much more advanced...ref:https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/passing-data-props-children/

Answer (score 0):

So thank's to @developer, this the `return` of `App.js`'s `render` function:

```
return (
  <main>
    <StopwatchManager
      showStopwatch={showStopwatch}
      initialSeconds={this.state.stopwatchInitialData.seconds}
      initialMinutes={this.state.stopwatchInitialData.minutes}
      initialHours={this.state.stopwatchInitialData.hours}
    />
    {main}
  </main>
);
```

`StopwatchManager` contains all the functionality of the stopwatch. It always rendered, but it decides to actually show the stopwatch by the `showStopwatch`prop.